# PDH performance counter instance names

Tags: c++, winapi, performancecounter

I'm trying to get performance information with PDH API. The problem I stuck into is that I can't bind process instances to counter instances: instance names always the same for different process instances.

e.g. performance counters for different *svchost* processes have instance names *svchost#1*, *svchost#2* etc. However PDH functions always return just svchost without the trailing numbers.

I used **PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE_ITEM.szName** to get instance names.

I also tried **PdhEnumObjectItems()** function with no luck: all returned instance names still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think PDH provides any way to tell the difference between two processes with the same name.

If this is causing a problem for you, you can go to the lower-level registry API. (PDH is a wrapper that tries to simplify use of performance counters, but the real API for V1 performance counters is RegQueryValueEx, and that's what PDH actually uses under the covers to read the V1 performance counter values. The Process performance counter is a V1 counter.) The low-level registry API provides the information in the PERF_INSTANCE_DEFINITION structure, and that includes a UniqueID field that might help. (Though it's possible that the Process performance counter doesn't actually set UniqueID to anything useful -- some performance counters set it to a good value, and others just set it to 0.)

In the future, I'm hoping that the Process performance counter will include the PID in the instance name, and that it will use the PID as the instance UniqueID, which would resolve the issue.